# Html drag'n'drop (browsers real drag'n'drop) image quality for Retina

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, drag-and-drop, retina-display

I set custom image on drag'n'drop start:

```
var dt = e.dataTransfer;
///...
dt.setDragImage(img, -20, -20);
```

But image quality for Retina is not good.
Usually, workaround of images quality for Retina is to make the image twice bigger and then either to "stratch" **background (with css) for 100%** or just to set **canvas size twice smaller** than its real content drawn.

But that **does not work** for the drag'n'drop image because the size of the image is the one which is shown on dragging as is, so I can do nothing with pixel rate.

Could anyone help on that? *At least, definitely confirm, that that's not possible* to solve with current browsers technologies level?

Thank you!

P.S. There is also some related topic with this drag'n'drop approach:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834181/dynamic-image-created-from-canvas-by-todataurl-on-dragstart-event-does-not-s